# What is the nicest way to make a function that takes Float or Double as input?

Tags: function, haskell, floating-point

Say I want to implement the Fermi function (the simplest example of a logistic curve) so that if it's passed a `Float` it returns a `Float` and if it's passed a `Double` it returns a `Double`. Here's what I've got:

```
e = 2.7182845904523536

fermiFunc :: (Floating a) => a -> a
fermiFunc x = let one = fromIntegral 1 in one/(one + e^(-x))
```

The problem is that ghc says `e` is a `Double`. Defining the variable `one` is also kinda gross. The other solution I've thought of is to just define the function for doubles:

```
e = 2.7182845904523536

fermiFuncDouble :: Double -> Double
fermiFuncDouble x = 1.0/(1.0 + e^(-x))
```

Then using `Either`:

```
fermiFunc :: (Floating a) => Either Float Double -> a
fermiFunc Right x = double2Float (fermiFuncDouble (float2Double x))
fermiFunc Left x = fermiFuncDouble x
```

This isn't very exciting though because I might as well have just written a separate function for the `Float` case that just handles the casting and calls `fermiFuncDouble`. Is there a nice way to write a function for both types?

Comment: The minimal change is to give `e` a polymorphic type signature just like you did for `fermiFunc`. Defining `one` isn't needed at all; just use `1` instead. But the answers here that suggest more radical changes are great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't write `e^x`, ever, in any language. That is not the exponential function, it's the *power function*.

The exponential function is called `exp`, and its definition actually has little to do with the power operation – it's defined, depending on your taste, as a Taylor series or as [the unique solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to the ordinary differential equation <sup>d</sup>⁄<sub>d</sub> exp  = exp  with boundary condition exp 0 = 1. Now, it so happens that, for any rational *n*, we have exp *n* ≡ (exp 1)<sup>*n*</sup> and that motivates also defining the power operation for numbers in ℝ or ℂ addition to ℚ, namely as

*a*<sup>*z*</sup> := exp (*z* · ln *a*)

...but *e* should be understood as really just a shortcut for writing exp() itself.

So rather than defining `e` somewhere and trying to take some power of it, you should use [`exp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:exp) just as it is.

```
fermiFunc :: Floating a => a -> a
fermiFunc x = 1/(1 + exp (-x))
```

...or indeed

```
fermiFunc = recip . succ . exp . negate
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you want floating point exponent, that's `(**)`. `(^)` is integral exponent. Rewriting your function to use `(**)` and letting GHC infer the type gives:

```
fermiFunc x = 1/(1 + e ** (-x))
```

and

```
> :t fermiFunc
fermiFunc :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

Since `Float` and `Double` both have `Floating` instances, `fermiFunc` is now sufficiently polymorphic to work with both.

(Note: you may need to declare a polymorphic type for `e` to get around the monomorphism restriction, i.e., `e :: Floating a => a`.)

In general, the answer to "How do I write a function that works with multiple types?" is either "Write it so that it works universally for all types." (parametric polymorphism, like `map`), "Find (or create) one or more typeclasses that they share that provides the behaviour you need." (ad hoc polymorphism, like `show`), or "Create a new type that is the sum of those types." (like `Either`).

The latter two have some tradeoffs. For instance, type classes are open (you can add more at any time) while sum types are closed (you must modify the definition to add more types). Sum types require you to know which type you are dealing with (because it must be matched up with a constructor) while type classes let you write polymorphic functions.

You can use `:i` in GHCi to list instances and to list instance methods, which might help you to locate a suitable typeclass.

Comment: Yes, however `e**(-x)` translates to `exp ((-x) * log e)`, where `log e` is a very inefficient way of writing `1`. (Though not quite as inefficient as defining `one = fromIntegral 1`, granted...)

Comment: That's true, and I'm glad your answer corrects this, but I think the rest of my answer is still useful. The misuse of `e` is somewhat tangential to the question, which is really about ad hoc polymorphism, imo.

Comment: `fermiFunc = recip . succ . exp . negate` is beautiful though.